# Feature extraction for Sentiment Analysis using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis

Which feature extractor (Countvectorizer, TfIdf)  will be best for sentiment analysis of tweets?
Can someone please explain the difference between each and which is most relevant for different classifiers.

I have planned to use 3 different classifiers- Naive Bayes,SVM and MaxEnt

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the SelectKBest method for selecting the top k most informative features for sentiment analysis. This is present in the scikit-learn library in Python.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html

You can import it as:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2, f_classif
```

Once you've read the documentation you can try using both the 'chi2' as well as 'f-classif' scores for feature extraction. SelectKBest is a good method to select your features because it selects the features that have the strongest association with the output variable. You can keep changing the value of k to experiment and see which value of k gives you the best results.

Comment: No i was actually looking for a feature extraction method and not a way of feature selection.

Comment: Tfidf and Count Vectorizer both give different results depending on your data. You can try both and see which gives you a better performance.